# Pause until function finishes running

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to write an app that certain markers on Google Maps. When a point is long pressed on the map, a dialog pops up where the user inputs the information about the point. This information will then be displayed in the marker's info window.

For the code I have written, when a point is long pressed, showEditDialog() runs and the dialog appears, but the app does not wait for the user to input the information and press OK before running the rest of the code in OnMapLongClick. This means that newly added points do not have this info because the app tries to load data from SharedPreferences before it is saved, but the information appears when app is restarted and all the markers are reloaded. How do I fix this?

Main Activity:

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);
            int locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);

            showEditDialog();

            locationCount++;

            String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name"+Integer.toString(locationCount-1), null);
            String url = sharedPreferences.getString("url"+Integer.toString(locationCount-1), null);
            // Drawing marker on the map
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()  
                .position(point)
                .title(name)
                .snippet(url)
            );

            /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            // Storing the latitude for the i-th location
            editor.putString("lat"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.latitude));

            // Storing the longitude for the i-th location
            editor.putString("lng"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.longitude));

            // Storing the count of locations or marker count
            editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);

            /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "New Camera Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

private void showEditDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    AddCamDialog addCamDialog = new AddCamDialog();
    addCamDialog.show(fm, "fragment_newcam");
}


@Override
public void onFinishEditDialog1(String EditText1) {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);
    int locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("name"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), EditText1);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onFinishEditDialog2(String EditText2) {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);
    int locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("url"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), EditText2);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Dialog class:

```
public class AddCamDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public interface AddCamDialogListener {
        void onFinishEditDialog1(String EditText1);
        void onFinishEditDialog2(String EditText2);
    }


    private EditText EditText1;
    private EditText EditText2;

    public AddCamDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.title_NewCamera);

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_newcam, null);
        EditText1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cam_name);
        EditText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cam_URL);

        builder.setView(view);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.PositiveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                AddCamDialogListener activity = (AddCamDialogListener) getActivity();
                activity.onFinishEditDialog1(EditText1.getText().toString());
                activity.onFinishEditDialog2(EditText2.getText().toString());

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.NegativeButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since those operations are asynchronous, you should trigger each stage according to the appropriate event, which in this case is the finish of the dialog, so put the code that should be executed only after the dialog is dismissed in `onFinishEditDialog1`/`onFinishEditDialog2`, not right after the call `showEditDialog`

Comment: What's the best way to get the latlng of the point if I put the code in onFinishEditDialog1/onFinishEditDialog2? Do I save it into SharedPreferences first then load it from there?

Comment: That's up to you, if you don't need it afterward, you don't need to save it to shared preferences. Also, you can reduce it to one callback with two parameters...